# Magento 2: How to show admin system configuration options conditionally?

Tags: magento2, custom, magento-2.1.3, system.xml, system-config

I have a dropdown in Magento 2 config setting. Now I want the setting to get displayed only when there are any options available for the dropdown, else it should be not shown. I also want to display a message in this case that "NO options are available currently". How can I implement that without breaking magento2 standards.

Answer (score 3):

Go to **Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Admin -> Admin Base URL**

Set  Use Custom Admin URL to "Yes" & below it's code

**magento\vendor\magento\module-backend\etc\adminhtml\system.xml**

```
<group id="url" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Admin Base URL</label>
                <field id="use_custom" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Use Custom Admin URL</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Admin\Usecustom</backend_model>
                </field>
                <field id="custom" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Custom Admin URL</label>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Admin\Custom</backend_model>
                    <depends>
                        <field id="use_custom">1</field>
                    </depends>
                    <comment>Make sure that base URL ends with '/' (slash), e.g. http://yourdomain/magento/</comment>
                </field>
                <field id="use_custom_path" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Use Custom Admin Path</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Admin\Custompath</backend_model>
                </field>
                <field id="custom_path" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="4" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Custom Admin Path</label>
                    <validate>required-entry validate-alphanum</validate>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Admin\Custompath</backend_model>
                    <depends>
                        <field id="use_custom_path">1</field>
                    </depends>
                    <comment>You will have to sign in after you save your custom admin path.</comment>
                </field>
            </group>
```

Here

```
 <depends>
    <field id="use_custom_path">1</field>
 </depends>
```

1 = Yes, 0 = No.

It depends on what select value you set on your dropdown.

Comment: NO, this is not what I am expecting, I already know this. Please read the description to understand my requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution for your problem. You can achieve what you are looking by below.
First you have to add a `frontend_class` to all the elements you want to hide. 
If you have two config fields like below.

```
<field id="enable_fields" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Select Option</label>
    <frontend_model>NAMESPACE\MODULENAME\Block\SelectOptions</frontend_model> <!-- Our block for adding select box -->
</field>

<field id="my_field_one" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Field One</label>
    <frontend_class>hide-this</frontend_class>
</field>

<field id="my_field_two" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Field Two</label>
    <frontend_class>hide-this</frontend_class>
</field>
```

Here, `enable_fields` field is the main field which will be the dropdown field as per your requirements. If there are options available for this field, then `my_field_one` and `my_field_two` will get displayed.
`my_field_one` and `my_field_two` has set `frontend_class` set to `hide-this`.
All elements with class name `hide-this` will be hidden if there is no option available for your first element.
Now create a block file,

```
<?php
namespace NAMESPACE\MODULENAME\Block;

class SelectOptions extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field {

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element) {
        $value = $element->getData('value');

        //YOUR IF CONDITION FOR CHECKING DROPDOWN OPTIONS

        $options = array( 1 =>'Option One', 2 => 'Option Two'); // Your Select Options
        $name = "groups[general][fields][enable_fields][value]"; // Make sure you are using correct path for your field
        $id = "enable_fields";

        $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select'
            )->setName(
                $name
            )->setId(
                $id
            )->setTitle(
                __("")
            )->setValue(
                $value
            )->setOptions(
                $options
            )->setExtraParams(
                'data-validate="{\'validate-select\':true}"'
            )->getHtml();

        // ELSE

        $html = '<p>There is no option available.</p>';
        $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">
           require(["jquery"], function ($) {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $(".hide-this").each(function(){
                        $(this).closest("tr").hide(); // Can also use .remove() to remove the field completely
                    })
                });
            });
        </script>';

        // END IF
        return $html;
    }
}
```